# Why is Chrome Console returning string for typeof null

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, null, typeof

Here is my code that is giving different results when run in Chrome versus other browsers(Safari/Firefox)

```js
var abc = null;
console.log(typeof abc);
```

**in Chrome:** `string`

**in Terminal:** `object`

**in Safari/Firefox:** `object`

Code run by node is also giving `object`.

Comment: chrome prints `object` for me. Not sure how you get `string`. Are you sure you don't have a typo and you accidentally wrote: `console.log((typeof typeof abc))` ?

Comment: I ran in the latest version of chrome and it returns `object`. What version of chrome are you using?

Comment: The spec says it should give object: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-35 (my chrome also gives object)

Comment: Impossible, object it is.

Comment: What is your Chrome version?

Comment: when i run the above code in chrome console it prints ```string```

Comment: ```Version 80.0.3987.122 (Official Build) (64-bit)``` and operating system is ```OSX```